# how can I add facebook profile link on my laravel website user profile. without copy form the url path

Tags: laravel, facebook, laravel-8, addition

I want to add some user Facebook, Instagram, and twitter profile link on my Laravel website all user profile. I have a Facebook click button , I want to click this button and then go to Facebook and just copy main profile link and back to my website profile. and as like as for Instagram and twitter. so how can I do this. please help me any one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/548gS.png)

Comment: Facebook doesn't give you the "real" link to the user profile any more via API. At most you can get a link with a token, that will only work for logged-in friends of the user.

Answer (score 1):

For example, Facebook, you must regist your web project  developer console page, set app key to your web project. Then, you can finally use facebook api to get user profile info.

You can use [Laravel socialate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite).